# Adding To List Saved In Isolated Storage WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

im trying to call a list and add and new item to the list using

```
 IsolatedStorageFile Settings1 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (Settings1.FileExists("MyStoreItems"))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Open))
            {                                
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
                listobj = (PanoramaApp5.StorageControl.MyDataList)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
                listobj.Add(new MyData { Name = filename, Location = ("/Downloaded/" + filename) });   
                serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, listobj);
            }
        }
```

i was using this before

```
listobj.Add(new MyData { Name = filename, Location = ("/Downloaded/" + filename) });


            if (Settings1.FileExists("MyStoreItems"))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
                    serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, listobj);

                }
                MessageBox.Show("Items stored successfully.");
            }
```

it kept adding to the list until i either came out of the page or closed the app, the it would just rewrite the list if called again.

How can i just add to the list without destroying the old list

Edit*

I am using the following Code to write to the list

```
 public static void writeisobtn_Click(string filename)
    {
        listobj.Add(new MyData { Name = filename });
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
            serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, listobj);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Items stored successfully.");

    }
```

This works fine, if i use wptools and get the file and open it with notepad++ i get

```
      <StorageControl.MyData><Name>TestName1</Name></StorageControl.MyData>     
      <StorageControl.MyData><Name>TestName2</Name></StorageControl.MyData>
```

i call the list using

```
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Open))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
                listobj = (MyDataList)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
            }
```

the list loads fine, i go back the page and add more names to the list and the list loads with the new names Aswel as the old, but how ever if i close and open the app and then add e.i TestName5 when i get the file and open it there is only one entry of TestName5

Comment: What do you mean *add to the list without destroying the old list*?

Comment: as i said when i close the app and go to app, reopen go to add something again, it wipes the list and the list just has the new items.

Comment: After you add new items to the list, you are writing the list to a file, then when you enter the app you are reading the file - am I right?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program, see how the list looks just before save/load operations?

Answer (score 0):

FileMode.Open, as your code has clearly asserted that the file exist.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Open))
```

You can also use (OpenOrCreate)

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
```

Then you don't need the FileExists check.

Comment: i have tried using OpenOrCreate Still get the same result, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I Sorted It Saving The File Like This

```
  public static void writeisobtn_Click(string filename)
    {
        MyDataList listobj = new MyDataList();
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Open))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
            listobj = (MyDataList)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
        }     


        listobj.Add(new MyData { Name = filename });

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
            serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, listobj);

        }
        MessageBox.Show("Items stored successfully.");

    }
```